# Differentiating products and quotients

Tags: calculus

I am studying maths as a hobby and have come across this problem:

Differentiate with respect to x:

$\frac{(x^2 + 1)(x - 1)^2}{(2x - 1)}$

Now if we say  $u =(x^2 + 1)$ and $v = (x - 1)^2$ and $w =(2x + 1)$ I would know how to find $\frac{dy}{dx}$ if the problem was $y = uv$ or $y = \frac{u}{v}$ but I cannot solve this, which involves 3 elements.

I have tried multiplying out the numerator to get a single equation but still cannot get the right answer.

The book answer is $\dfrac{2x(x - 1)(3x^2 - 3x + 2)}{(2x - 1)^2}$

I have eventually boiled it down to this:

$$\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{ (2x-1)\{(x-1)^2\cdot 2x + 2(x^2+1)(x-1)  \} - 2(x^2+1)(x-1)^2 }{(2x-1)^2}$$

Comment: If you wish to use chain rule, take $w = \frac{1}{2x+1}$. Now you have $y = uvw$ and $y' = u'vw + uv'w +uvw'$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just apply the rules as you need to. To make the procedure more clear, I'll use $u,v,w$ for the pieces in your problem (you can use the original pieces and actually perform the indicated differentiations).

The overall form is a fraction, so first use the quotient rule:

$$\left(\frac{uv}{w}\right)' = \frac{(uv)'w - (uv)w'}{w^2}$$
Then in the numerator, you see $(uv)'$, which needs the product rule
$$(uv)' = u'v + uv'$$
So put it together to get

$$\left(\frac{uv}{w}\right)' = \frac{(u'v + uv')w - (uv)w'}{w^2}$$
and simplify as needed. You typically may need to rearrange the result to get it to match the form of the answer in the book, but that shouldn't be too hard.

---

**Addendum:** Check your work. I see $(2x+1)$ in the original denominator, but you have $(2x-1)$.

Comment: Add the book’s answer and your work at the top so we can see where you went wrong

Comment: Note that you seem to have $(2x-1)$ in the denominator, but the original problem has $(2x+1)$, so one of them must be wrong

Comment: I worked with your expression and was able to reduce it to the book's answer. Are you still having trouble? Note that you can factor a $2(x-1)$ out of the expression in curly braces $\{\cdots\}$, so it will factor out of the whole numerator. Then work **carefully** with what's left in the numerator.

Comment: Thanks MPW. I solved it using your method.  Took me ages but I now feel I have a much better understanding.

Answer (score 1):

**HINT:**

Use logarithmic differentiation.

$$y=\frac{(x^2 + 1)(x - 1)^2}{(2x + 1)}$$

$$\ln y=\ln(x^2 + 1)+2\ln(x - 1)-\ln(2x+1)$$

$$\frac 1y \frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{2x}{1+x^2}+\cdots\cdots$$

This is particularly useful when you have multiple functions multiplied/divided or if in powers.

Comment: It's likely that the derivative of a logarithm has not yet been covered, given the nature of the problem and the OP's unfamiliarity when both the product and quotient rules are used together. Later, however, logarithmic differentiation is certainly one way of approaching this.

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro I understand. I'll let this be as it is, since another answer has been added addressing OP's needs